# How to make absolute jumps relative?

Tags: assembly, x86

Given I have x86 assembly code disassembled into a list of structures that fully describe it (opcode, regs, imm, etc.), how can I programmatically turn absolute jumps to relative jumps?

Basically what I try to achieve is that I can insert or delete bytes between jump and destination and afterwards fix the jump simply by adding the delta to it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is to simply adjust the addresses.

Comment: Sorry, I was very unclear. I edited the question.

Comment: I won't pretend to have any expertise in x86 (i was a Mot 68K partisan 3 decades ago).  after reading @MichaelT's answer, i am a bit confused as to what it is you want to do.

I thought the question was about self-modifying code: code that is loaded and run, but gets a part of it moved somewhere else and executed from there.  Is that it?  If so, you need to modify the addresses everywhere there is an absolute jump.  **or** you need to change the assembly instruction to do relative jumps in the first place. (and why aren't you doing that?)

Comment: and can you post a snippet of the disassembled code to point at to elucidate your question?

Comment: ah, after re-reading i am getting a better picture.  so you want to wedge in some code or data between code that is tranversed with some jump references?  that's a problem with either absolute or relative jumps.

Comment: But with relative jumps it is easy to fix, because I can simply add the bytes that I changed to the relative address. Iff the change was made between the jump and the destination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets start out by making a distinction between *assembly* and *machine* code.  These are often seen as something very similar, and they are, but there's a step between the assembly language and the machine language - that of the assembler.

People don't work in machine code anymore (they did *long* ago) its too much of a pain. Working with an assembler gives you the ability to use labels and in some cases, higher level opcodes. The assembler can then translate the labels and higher level opcodes into machine code.

When you disassemble a binary, you are getting the translation of the machine code back into assembly. But not all of the information for assembly is there. In particular, the labels are not there.  Without the labels, you have jump and read addresses that are fixed.  That was what the assembler did converting the *initial* assembly into machine code.

If you want to get the labels back, you need to add them. Go through and label every address that is used as a jump or branching target. Then convert every use of that address to its label and go forward from there.  Remember that you need to add *all* of the labels and do this because you will be shifting thing around.  Adding an instruction or two near the top will push *everything* after it to a new address.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I understand the difference between machine code and assembly. And I see that I can regenerate the labels by looking at where a branch goes. But this is only true for reletive branches, rigth? What happens with absolute jumps, I can't just look where they point to, because the address could be generated dynamically?

Comment: @Benjoyo you will likely still find either a jump table as a data structure somewhere, or a base + offset. You likely won't find complex math statements for where to jump to. If you *do* find odd jump structures, you would then need to look at it if it was any other code.  But you still need to identify all the targets for jumps *first* before you can go and start modifying it.

Comment: ok, I see. Are there any ressources or keywords where I can find information on what methods compilers use to calculate those addresses? So that I maybe can implement algorithms for at least specific compilers to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Benjoyo That depends quite a bit on the optimizations that are in play.  You might wish to look at writing some code in C, and then tossing it through [various compilers](https://gcc.godbolt.org) ([example](http://goo.gl/BfkmcB)) to see how different structures correspond to different assembly.  Though note that this is all assembly from C rather than assembly from disassembled machine code (there are labels there).